# Different theme for select icon and menu in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to set different themes for select menu icon and the dropdown which opens on clicking the icon.

Normally, the icon color is same as the `data-theme` attribute. I want that icon should be of different color and select menu should be of different color.

```
<select data-iconpos="notext" data-divider-theme="a" data-theme="c">
```

For eg: in the above code both select icon and menu will have `data-theme="c"`.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/D45JV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like that? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/D45JV/2/

You need to update the ui classes to get this. In this demo, I set select icon theme to `a` and option theme to `b`.

## JQUERY

```
$('.ui-select a').on('click', function(){
    $('.ui-selectmenu-list li').removeClass('ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-b').addClass('ui-btn-up-a ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-b').attr('data-theme', 'b');
});
```